# Angular 5: APP_INITIALIZER runs on every route

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using APP_INITIALIZER in an angular 5 app which loads some configurations from API call.

My expectation from APP_INITIALIZER is that it should be run only once when the app loads for the first time but I am seeing my APP_INITIALIZER logic being run every time I navigate to a new route.

Does APP_INITIALIZER run on every route change and is there a way to run it only once?
Pseudo code:

```
//app.module.ts
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppLoadService } from './app-load.service';

export function loadInitialData(appLoadService: AppLoadService) {
  return () => appLoadService.loadInitialData();
}

{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: loadInitialData,
  deps: [AppLoadService],
  multi: true
  }


// app-load.service.ts
loadInitialData(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const getConfig= this.http.get<any>(URL);
    return getConfig.subscribe(response=> {
      return resolve();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post code of how you are using it? It should only run once. Add AppLoadModule to app.module imports

```
 //appload.module.ts
        import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
        import { AppLoadService } from './app-load.service';


        export function init_app(appLoadService: AppLoadService) {
            return () => appLoadService.initializeApp();
        }

        @NgModule({

            providers: [
              AppLoadService,
              { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: init_app, deps: [AppLoadService], multi: true }

            ]
          })
          export class AppLoadModule { }



@Injectable()
export class AppLoadService {

  constructor(

  ) { }

  initializeApp(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve();

          // setTimeout(() => {         

          //   //do something
          //   console.log("App Loaded");

          //   resolve();

          // }, 1000);

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: similar to what you are doing. Update my question with code

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, I did move to Angular 6 before using so maybe there's a bug in 5